# Send JSON with unusual keys

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, object

I've object in js with keys-selectors:

```
{
    "[data-index="0"]": {
       // something
    },
    "> .class > .one": {
       key: "very bad+ \"\' string"
    }
 }
```

How send this object via ajax without any changes in the keys and with correct values?

By correct values I mean that "very bad+ \"\' string" should be total escaped, but save all chars and signs to store in Database.

PS. I know that i can send objects via AJAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` will transform your object into a JSON string. It can handle special characeters, don't worry.

```
var json = JSON.stringify(myObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you modify your object a bit

```
var obj = {
    "[data-index='0']": {
        // something
    },
    "> .class > .one": {
        key: "very bad+ \"\' string"
    }
}
```

then a `JSON.stringify(obj)` works. The second pair of `"` after `data-index=` provokes an error.

-- *edited syntax*